# Unable to push my rails app to heroku, says there's a gemfile error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, command-line

I'm a newbie, trying to push my rails application to heroku but it says push rejected.

I've looked at some similar issues on stackoverflow but none of the solutions seem to resolve it for me.

Here's the code from the terminal

```
Counting objects: 234, done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (200/200), done.
Writing objects: 100% (234/234), 393.61 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 234 (delta 37), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote:
remote: -----> Ruby app detected
remote: -----> Compiling Ruby/Rails
remote:
remote:  !
remote:  !     There was an error parsing your Gemfile, we cannot continue
remote:  !     /app/tmp/buildpacks/b7af5642714be4eddaa5f35e2b4c36176b839b4abcd9bfe57ee71c358d71152b4fd2cf925c5b6e6816adee359c4f0f966b663a7f8649b0729509d510091abc07/vendor/ruby/heroku-18/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems.rb:289:in `find_spec_for_exe': can't find gem bundler (>= 0.a) with executable bundle (Gem::GemNotFoundException)
remote:  !     from /app/tmp/buildpacks/b7af5642714be4eddaa5f35e2b4c36176b839b4abcd9bfe57ee71c358d71152b4fd2cf925c5b6e6816adee359c4f0f966b663a7f8649b0729509d510091abc07/vendor/ruby/heroku-18/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems.rb:308:in `activate_bin_path'
remote:  !     from /tmp/d20190419-87-z1jfer/bundler-2.0.1/bin/bundle:23:in `<main>'
remote:  !
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app.
remote:
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote:
remote: !       Push rejected to london-learning.
remote:
To https://git.heroku.com/london-learning.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/london-learning.git'
```

And this is my Gemfile

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
ruby '2.4.4'

gem 'bootsnap', require: false
gem 'devise'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
gem 'pg', '~> 0.21'
gem 'puma'
gem 'rails', '5.2.1'
gem 'redis'

gem 'autoprefixer-rails'
gem 'font-awesome-sass', '~> 5.6.1'
gem 'sassc-rails'
gem 'simple_form'
gem 'uglifier'
gem 'webpacker'

group :development do
  gem 'web-console', '>= 3.3.0'
end

group :development, :test do
  gem 'pry-byebug'
  gem 'pry-rails'
  gem 'listen', '~> 3.0.5'
  gem 'spring'
  gem 'spring-watcher-listen', '~> 2.0.0'
  gem 'dotenv-rails'
end
```

Any help at all would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Have you seen https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/bundler-version? Looks related

Answer (score 0):

Try manually install bundler

```
gem install bundler -v 1.17.3
bundle _1.17.3_ install
git commit -am "Bundler 1.17.3 was installed"
git push heroku master
```

Comment: Hmm it doesn't seem to like the second line:
Could not find command "_1.17.3_"

What is the 2nd line trying to achieve?

Comment: Copy line by line and execute. It's right syntax. 2nd line executes with specific version of bundler.

Comment: Yeah, it still says Could not find command "_1.17.3_".
(with underscores around the number) after executing the second line

Comment: This comes up after running first line

/home/alxf95/.rbenv/rbenv.d/exec/gem-rehash/rubygems_plugin.rb:6: warning: Insecure world writable dir /home/alxf95/.rbenv/versions in PATH, mode 040777
Successfully installed bundler-1.17.3
1 gem installed